# Deleting multiple words from a file using terminal

Tags: bash, edit

I have a list of words `word1 word2 word3` which I want to delete from a file `file.txt`. How can i do that using terminal.

Comment: `sed -r -i 's/\bword1\b|\bword2\b|\bword3\b//g' file`?

Comment: Try using `sed` to replace those words with nothing.

Comment: Use `sed 's/word1//g` and repeat for the other words

Comment: @Floris this is not a good way. Say I want to delete arrest and arrested. First applying command for arrest and then arrested will leave "ed"s in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

- Replacements should only occur for *whole* words, not just any substrings.
- Replacements should occur *in-place* - i.e., the results should be written back to the input file.

---

- GNU `sed` (adapted from @jaypal's comment):

  ```
  sed -r -i 's/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b//g' file.txt
  ```
- FreeBSD/OSX `sed`:

  ```
  sed -E -i '' 's/[[:<:]](word1|word2|word3)[[:>:]]//g' file.txt
  ```

---

Variant solution in case the *search words* can be *substrings* of each other:

```
# Array of sample search words.
words=( 'arrest' 'arrested' 'word3' )

# Sort them in reverse order and build up a list of alternatives
# for use with `sed` later ('word3|arrested|arrest').
# Note how the longer words among words that are substrings of
# each other come before the shorter ones.
reverseSortedAlternativesList=$(printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}" | sort -r  | tr '\n' '|')
# Remove the trailing '|'.
reverseSortedAlternativesList=${reverseSortedAlternativesList%|}

# GNU sed:
sed -r -i 's/\b('"$reverseSortedAlternativesList"')\b//g' file.txt

# FreeBSD/OSX sed:
sed -E -i '' 's/[[:<:]]('"$reverseSortedAlternativesList"')[[:>:]]//g' file.txt
```

Comment: How to redirect output to new file instead of modifying it in place?

Comment: Remove the `-i` option (and its argument `''`, if on FreeBSD/OSX) and simply append `> out.txt` to redirect output to file `out.txt`; adapting the first snippet (modify the others analogously): `sed -r 's/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b//g' file.txt > out.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/word1//g" | sed "s/word2//g"
```

If you want to write the content into a new file do this:

```
cat file.txt | sed "s/word1//g" | sed "s/word2//g" > newfile.txt
```

Comment: How can I ensure that if word1 is substring of word2 e.g.(1=arrest and 2=arrested) then if the text contains arrested then it does not leave "ed"s in the text?